# background-image: url() does not work when you open the html by an express app

Tags: html, css, express

When I open the html file clicking on it, it works the background-image: url(), but when I open this file inside the expressapp by using res.sendFile(), it does not work.The rest of css code works as normal in both cases and the html code works too. In conclusion, everything except the background-image works perfectly so I do not think that the problem is something of the rest of code or the app and I think it is just that the background-image does not work in express app, so I would like to know if there is a solution for this like a different way to avoid this problem or that maybe I am actually doing something wrong for this. I tried to add the image in a ejs file that I use in the app but it does not work too, only the rest of css code.

I do not know if I can add images in the question because I wanted to add a photo to show the folder of the express app and the path to image, so I have to say that the home.html file and the app.js file are inside the folder of the express app and the image inside this express app but, as usual, in the path "/public/images" (from the express app folder) that is created in a express app.

I have tried putting the absolute path, with only '/' at the beginning and the current one. I tried to find a different solution but I found that nobody had this problem (normally it works) or maybe is because I found incorrectly.

```
//home.html
//This is only the head of the html file
// the only important is the background-image: url(), that does not work 
//in express.
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-image: url("./public/images/aghhome.jpg");
            background-color: white;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 50px;
            border-style: solid;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
        button {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


//app.js
// the main js file of the express app
// this a part of the code where I open this file by sendFile()

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/home.html'));
});
```

I expect that the image will appear as a background when I use the express app, not only when I open the html file directly in the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
//home.html
//This is only the head of the html file
// the only important is the background-image: url(), that does not work 
//in express.
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-image: url("./images/aghhome.jpg");
            background-color: white;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 50px;
            border-style: solid;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
        button {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


//app.js
// the main js file of the express app
// this a part of the code where I open this file by sendFile()

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/home.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved it, I do not know why I have to quit the public part if images is inside the public folder but I am glad that is working.

Comment: Because you have been config `static path` in  `app.js`.

You can go https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html for more detail

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here might be that in your body tag to change the background image you are using a dot. Try this.

```html
background-image: url("/public/images/aghhome.jpg");
```

Comment: Sorry, but I said that I tried before with only "/" and the absolute path, but thanks.